# jQuery populate Select list based on text input's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection

I am trying to write code that allows a select list to be populated based on the input value of a textbox. 
 For Example:
 If user inputs milk in the textbox, the select list will contain `"full fat", "Skimmed", "1% Milk"`
I have been online and can't find any information on how to do this. I have managed to autopopulate one select list based on the selection from a previous one using jquery. However, I cant find a solution for when using a textbox. 
Thanks for checking out my question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create an object containing arrays of options:

```
selectOptions = {
   milk: ["full fat", "Skimmed", "1% Milk"]
}
```

based on this, you can append `<option>` tags to the `<select>` when the `onchange` event of the `<textarea>` fires:

```
$('textarea').change(function() {
   if(selectOptions[$(this).val()]) { // does the selectOptions object have an entry for the value of the textarea?
       $.each(selectOptions[$(this).val()], function() { // for each array item do
           $('select').append('<option>' + this + '</option>'); // append an option tag for the array item
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have tried, but it doesnt seem to work. Think i'm going wrong somewhere. If I entered milk in the text box would the select list be populated with "full fat", "skimmed", "1% Milk"?

Comment: the onchange event fires if you deselect the textbox.. you can also use onkeyup, which fires on each keypress.

Comment: sorry.. i hadn't tested the code i wrote ;) i updated it and it works now.. look here for a testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/xeVBm/4/

Comment: Ok I tried but still can't get it to work. Thanks so much for your time but could you see what I have done and tell me where I'm going wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/echoes13/C83DB/

Comment: the object you defined has a syntax error. use the javascript console!! (i recommend firebug if you use firefox)

Comment: When I try to add another option to the object the select list shows all the options, even those from other options in the array. Do you know how i could fix that? Thankyou again.